# How to disable customization for the TabBar?

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

within my App it should be forbidden to edit (customize) the TabBar. This means there should be no edit button and no other possibility to change the order of the items.

(this is not my decision, the boss wants it that way :) )

I can't find a property to do this - so is this possible after all?

cheers

Comment: Sounds harsh... "Forbidden"... EDIT: And, you're blaming it on the boss too, such *chutzpah*... :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController 
{
tabBarController.NaviController.navigationBar.topItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

the best way that worked for me is to set the 'customizableViewControllers' of UITabBarcontroller to nil,so this will not show 'edit' button over more tab bar item.

Ex.

```
self.tabBarController.customizableViewControllers = nil;
```

Comment: I thought this was a more elegant way of doing the same. However, I find the edit button remains visible on iPhones running 4.0.2. (Your solution Works great on iOS 4.3.5)